# Understanding a limit on $R^n$ in a more rigorous way

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

> **Definition**: A function $f:A\subset R^n\to R^m$ is said to be differentiable at a point $a\in A$ if there exists a real $m\times n$ matrix $B$ such that the following equality holds:
>   $$
> \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-Bh}{|h|} = 0
> $$

I'm using the usual definitions of limit and metric on $R^n$. I have the following theorem with it's demonstration:

> **Theorem**: If $f:A\subset R^n\to R^m$ is differentiable at $a\in A$, then $f$ is continuous at $a$.
>
> *Proof: We can write $$f(a+h)-f(a) = |h|\left[ \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-Bh}{|h|}\right]+Bh$$ **so** $f(a+h)-f(a)\to 0$ as $h\to 0$ therefore $f$ is continuous at $a$.*

My aim is to rewrite the demonstration using epsilons and deltas, especially the implication denoted by the bolded word in the box above. So I started this way (I'll use $e$ and $d$ instead of greek letters for short):

Given $e>0$, we have that there exists $d>0$ such that 
$$
0<|h|<d \implies \left|\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-Bh}{|h|}\right|<e
$$
then we can write
$$
|f(a+h) - f(a)|= \left||h|\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-Bh}{|h|}+Bh\right|
$$
$$
\le |h|\left|\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-Bh}{|h|}\right| + |Bh|
$$

But I don't know what to do next to bound this last expression, because of the terms $|h|$ and $|Bh|$. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For small $d>0$, one has $0<|h|<d$ implies $\left|f(a+h)-f(a)-Bh\right|/|h|<1$, and $|h|<(1+\|B\|)^{-1}\epsilon$, so $|f(a+h)-f(a)|<|h|+|Bh|\leq|h|+\|B\||h|=(1+|B|)|h|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Nice! I'm just a little bit confused about how you got $|Bh|\le ||B|| |h|$.

Comment: That is the definition of an operator norm.

Comment: Yes! But I only know this property for normed vector spaces of matrices with sum and scalar product given by vector space axioms. Can you give me some hint on how I show this inequality if I have the product of two matrices $m\times n$ and $n\times 1$ defined on that space?

Comment: If you define $\|M\|$ for a matrix to be the sum of square of its entries and then taking radical out most, you should be able to deduce that "operator norm" inequality as well.

Comment: I think that the $B$ in question cannot represent a operator since $Bh$ is not on the space of $n\times 1$ matrices.

Comment: The $B$ you need to make it as an $m\times n$ matrix, this is tricky.